# Multi-dimensional regression with Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, vowpalwabbit

I have an unusual regression problem that I'm trying to fit into vowpal wabbit. I'm trying to learn a set of regressors **{r_m(x)}** that train on the data set **{(x_n, h_n[m])}** for n=1 to n=N, where *m* indexes the *M* dimensions. This basically means there are *M* separate regression problems.

I am wondering if it is possible to merge all *M* problems into just 1, by relegating each problem into its own namespace. E.g. inside the .vw training file, I'll have the following:

```
h_1[m=0] |firstnamespace x_1_features
h_2[m=0] |firstnamespace x_2_features
...      |...            ...
h_N[m=0] |firstnamespace x_N_features
----------------------------------------------------------------
h_1[m=1] |secondnamespace x_1_features
h_2[m=1] |secondnamespace x_2_features
...      |...             ...
h_N[m=1] |secondnamespace x_N_features
----------------------------------------------------------------
h_1[m=M] |lastnamespace x_1_features
h_2[m=M] |lastnamespace x_2_features
...      |...           ...
h_N[m=M] |lastnamespace x_N_features
```

Then I can just perform

```
vw -d Train.vw -f Train.model -c --loss_function squared
    --invert_hash model_readable.txt
```

and obtain the regressor weights for each namespace.

I know this strategy is similar to the transformation/reduction of a multi-label classification problem into multiple binary classification problems: [this link](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/topics/1391). I am wondering if the same can be applied to regression problems without any cross-talk between the dimensions, i.e. vowpal wabbit treating each namespace independently.

If it's important to note, I have *M* = 400, *N* = 4e6, and the number of data dimensions is equal to the number of unique word tokens in the whole document set...

Comment: On a first thought: assuming you have no hash collisions (which is reasonable to assume for such a small M), the name-space separation will ensure total separation of the input features, but unfortunately, it will not ensure separation of the label (target feature).  Adding a unique constant feature to each group: in_M1, in_M2, ... may help segregation if their target labels weighted-avg is different but it can not eliminate the target cross-talk completely since in the end, vw tries to minimize loss on the full training-set target label and builds a single model for the full train-set.

Comment: So you suggest adding in_m1, in_m2, ... ,in_mM constants and using the --noconstant parameter? And by weighted-avg you mean that of each namespace's respective regressor weights?

Comment: I'm saying that adding the in_M<n> features will help.  But as you cannot separate the target label between the M spaces, this is only a half-way "solution". Also, I would leave the global constant alone since it can help account for a global bias which may exist.